# Can't use ftp to transfer a file - permission denied

Tags: bash, mysql, c++, ftp, curl

I'm using Ubuntu and I would like to have a script that once a day transfer my mysql database from my local hard drive to my ftp server (provider is Aruba).

I'm correctly able to connect via FTP and transfer file when I use Filezilla, but I'm having problem when I use ftp.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -u root isola > bdd-13-11-2019.sql
ftp -n > ftp_$$.log <<EOF
 verbose
 open ftp.robo-dyne.com 
 user XXXXXXXX@aruba.it
 my_password
 put bdd-13-11-2019.sql
 bye
EOF
```

I always get this error:

```
Verbose mode on.
Connected to ftp.robo-dyne.com.
220-#
220-#                                 
220-#  Aruba.it                    
220-#  The Web Hosting Company     
220-#                                 
220-#
220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
331 User XXXXXX@aruba.it OK. Password required
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
local: bdd-13-11-2019.sql remote: bdd-13-11-2019.sql
200 PORT command successful
553 Can't open that file: Permission denied
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

I don't need to stricly use ftp, I can use any other solution.
I already tried to use curl with no success.

EDIT: permissions on file are:

```
isola@isola-virtual-machine:~/Documents/Isola02$ whoami
isola
isola@isola-virtual-machine:~/Documents/Isola02$ ls -la | grep bdd
-rw-rw-rw- 1 isola isola 1619317 nov 13 22:18 bdd-13-11-2019.sql
```

EDIT2: it doesn't work neither from the terminal:

```
ftp> open ftp.robo-dyne.com
Connected to ftp.robo-dyne.com.
220-#
220-#                                 
220-#  Aruba.it                    
220-#  The Web Hosting Company     
220-#                                 
220-#
220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
Name (ftp.robo-dyne.com:isola): xxxxxx@aruba.it
331 User xxxxxx@aruba.it OK. Password required
Password:
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> put ftp_22584.log 
local: ftp_22584.log remote: ftp_22584.log
200 PORT command successful
553 Can't open that file: Permission denied
ftp> bye
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

Comment: "553 Can't open that file: Permission denied"  what are the permission of the file?

Comment: -rw-rw-rw- 1 isola isola 1619317 nov 13 22:02 bdd-13-11-2019.sql

Comment: and the ftp user is isola or added to the group isola?

Comment: I edited the first topic to add the result of whoami and ls -la. However, isola is the user on my local pc and i'm logged as isola; it doesn't work even if I use root.

Comment: ok, you are connecting into FTP server now? You can't be logging in anonymously then. you need to log into server with the ID that has root privileges on FTP server.

Comment: I see `Current restricted directory is /`. Have you tried to change dir to your home?

Comment: Yes and it uploads the file but the file has 0 bytes.

Comment: strictly speaking, is this really an Ubuntu-specific question?

Comment: my Os is Ubuntu, Os server is Ubuntu, i'm using a linux-based terminal to send commands with the ftp utility. What should this be? A MS Windows-specific question?

Answer (score 1):

I post my comment as answer in order to help other users with the same problem.

I solved the problem by taking into accounts these points:

1. the main folder was not writable, so I needed to `cd` to the subfolder
2. use `PASV` mode
3. use `binary` mode to transfer file

Answer (score 0):

One clue--filezilla is frequently running in root privileged (sp?) mode. If you set it to run that way, and transfer works, I would use filezilla myself. Then it will not matter about the perms on the file. I do not know how to script this, have used filezilla routinely.

maybe you could try ftp as root by using sudo? Looking at the script again, try logging into the server with the admin id of isola.

ok, you are connecting into FTP server now? You can't be logging in anonymously then. you need to log into server with the ID that has root privileges on FTP server.

Comment: filezilla is used as normal user and it works fine; I already tried to use ftp as root, but nothing change. I can understand if it's a problem related to my local file (I tried with different files/different paths) or to another aspect.

Comment: I added the output if I try to directly launch ftp from terminal and not from script.